# Getting strange error when trying to login through "su user"

Tags: debian, ssh, users, su

When I'm login as root, all is fine, but when I'm trying to log in directly with user or "su username" command I'm getting this. Does anyone have thoughts about why this might happen?

```
(1:43)# su username
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/bin/lshell", line 52, in <module>
        main()
      File "/usr/bin/lshell", line 38, in main
        userconf = CheckConfig(args).returnconf()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/lshell/checkconfig.py", line 71, in __init__
        self.get_config()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/lshell/checkconfig.py", line 286, in get_config
        self.get_config_sub('default')
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/lshell/checkconfig.py", line 316, in get_config_sub
        conf = self.config.items(section) + conf
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/backports/configparser/__init__.py", line 880, in items
        return [(option, value_getter(option)) for option in d.keys()]
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/backports/configparser/__init__.py", line 877, in <lambda>
        section, option, d[option], d)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/backports/configparser/__init__.py", line 384, in before_get
        self._interpolate_some(parser, option, L, value, section, defaults, 1)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/backports/configparser/__init__.py", line 433, in _interpolate_some
        "found: %r" % (rest,))
    backports.configparser.InterpolationSyntaxError: '%' must be followed by '%' or '(', found: u"%u'"
```

Comment: It looks like this user is using `/usr/bin/lshell` as the shell.  This is a "limited shell" written in python.  Do you get the same error if you just run `lshell`?   You may need to reinstall the `lshell` package.

Comment: @StephenHarris Yeah, if i just run `lshell` im getting an error.

Comment: `su` switches user, adding a second account's privileges to an existing login session.  It _does not_ log in.